# Allow phone calls to members of a list without exposing numbers to caller

Tags: privacy, proxy, phone

I'm working with a non-profit that is trying to check in with many members. Under normal conditions they would have a caller on site using an on site phone list to make those calls, but are now needing to distribute that work to callers working from home. They are not comfortable transmitting sensitive member information to devices outside their office.

Are there free software solutions for connecting callers to receivers without giving the caller the real, unencrypted phone numbers? They're specifically looking for a way to make phone calls as it is the avenue of communication they have had the most trouble with. Other avenues, such as social media, have resolved themselves organically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I doubt you'd be able to find a free solution for this since someone would have to bear the cost of the infrastructure to place the calls to phone numbers unless perhaps there's something which is ad-supported, but I question whether such a service could be economically viable and thus whether one may exist.

For low-cost solutions which could may be able to be used to do something like this, you could check out twilio.com (big name) or bandwidth.com (used by Zoom, RingCentral, Skype, and Google Voice I think).